# Implementing Aura: 'WARNING: Access Check Failed! ComponentService.getDef():'markup://namespace:component' is not visible to 'undefined'.'

Tags: lightning-apps, aura

I'm trying to implement Aura into my project and while debugging I have seen this error in my browsers dev console:

> WARNING: Access Check Failed!
>   ComponentService.getDef():'markup://print:print' is not visible to
>   'undefined'.

I have not found any documentation on what this is and how to stop this warning. What must I do to stop this warning?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug as far as I know of the debugger.

check out this thread:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008dV3AAI